# Read Android Camera From PC

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to connect my Adroid Mobile Device to my PC via USB and figure out a way to stream the camera live on my screen and be able to work with it with the android platform. How would one go about doing this? Eventually I would like to be able to track a florescent object with the camera and calculate properties about distance, height, width, etc. Not sure what environment I should start with to achieve this. Any links to point me in the right direction would be excellent.

Answer (score 0):

I did try to do this a few times ago (but I gave up). I started by looking about it on the driver side of things. Too complex (for me at least I admit). And I found an application on the market that did that and also a student project still in progress. I looked more into it and here's how it's working. Note that's it's just a way of doing it, there may be other solutions.

- create an android application that stream the video content on the sd card of the phone (or wherever you want)
- create in this android application a webserver that can respond to request from the outer world
- map some special url of your webserver android application to the files generated by the video camera

From your pc, you then just have to access the webserver of your phone and voilà. Ok that's not that easy but you understand the principles.

Here's the student projet (source code included yay!) :

http://code.google.com/p/camdroiduni/

Here's the application on the market I was talking about :

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en